# How to run fsck on /etc

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, fsck

It seems that a part of my filesystem is corrupted.

```
vm-rhel7:/home/robert# dir /etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100/rhsmcertd
ls: cannot access /etc/selinux/targeted/active/modules/100/rhsmcertd: Structure needs cleaning
```

This is, what I have in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/vg00-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
```

How can I run fsck in this situation? I have tried /forcefsck several times, thus fsck probably already proceeded, but the error remains. Is there any other advice to resolve the problem? This is remote virtual RHEL7, I do not have a physical access to it.

Comment: You dont fsck directories, you fsck block devices which should not be mounted when being fsck'd.  This puts you somewhat in a bind as /etc appears to be on the root block device.  Are you able to somehow turn off this vm and set up another one which boots off an alternative block device and makes available to fsck?  Otherelwise copying your data to a replacement VM may be your best bet....

Comment: There may be one other thing you can try - but its not risk free. As per https://www.golinuxcloud.com/force-file-system-check-on-boot-systemd-fsck/ you may be able to modify the grub bootloader to tell the OS to force an fsck on startup, then reboot (using the parameters  fsck.mode=force and fsck.repair=yes)